# SQL: shopping cart design for a marketplace

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a marketplace that requires the user to be logged in to add items to the shopping cart. In most online examples, I can't see the benefits of creating a separate `cart` and `cart_item` tables.

Example: https://mysql.tutorials24x7.com/blog/guide-to-design-database-for-shopping-cart-in-mysql

Why not just create an empty `order` and set its `status` to `cart` and when the user submits the `order`, then just reduce the quantities from the `product` table and fill the other columns with the required values and change the `status` of the `order`?

Example with shopping cart
[image]

Example using the `order` table to act as a cart when setting its `status` to `cart`.
[image]

Comment: Hmm, this may be a bit opinion based, but I see no logical reason it would be wrong to interpret the cart as an order in the making. So your approach seems generally valid to me.

Comment: please don't post the same  question on SO and DBA

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross-posted to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your use cases. Having the `cart` and `cart_item` tables in the first example is just an extra level of **normalization** which may be needed in some contexts (depending on how different a `cart_item` is vs an `ordet_item` etc). But generally speaking, and based on the schema you've designed, it's totally acceptable to eliminate the idea of a `cart` and `cart_item` entity entirely, if the `order` and `order_item` can support all your use cases for that workflow without much complication in your backend code.

You could even take it one step further and not touch the database at all until the `order` has been placed. Rather than storing an "*in-process order*" in the database, you can take the route of just storing an object representation, such as JSON on the client side, until the `order` is submitted (which is when in the workflow your backend code can convert that JSON to your database entities and persist it in the `order` and `order_item` tables respectively). This is one implementation some websites take, and will temporarily persist it on the client side such as in **session storage** (which is why you'll find on some websites your items only temporarily stay in the cart).

But regardless, it really just depends on the use cases of your workflow whether you choose option A or B in your post, or option C that I just mentioned. They're all valid choices.